# Examine consecutive rows within a given user and identify when value in another column changes in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data

```
user_df = read.table(text = "person_id job_number job_type start_date end_date
                  1 1 B 2012-11-01 2014-01-01
                  1 2 A 2016-02-01 2016-10-01
                  1 3 A 2016-12-01 2020-01-01
                  1 4 B 2020-01-01 2021-01-01
                  2 1 A 2011-03-01 2012-08-01
                  2 2 B 2013-01-01 2020-01-01
                  2 3 A 2020-01-01 2021-01-01
                  2 4 B 2021-01-01 2021-01-17
                  3 1 A 2005-03-01 2011-03-01
                  3 2 B 2012-01-01 2014-01-01", header = T)
```

Each `person_id` will have a variable number of jobs that can have one of many types (in this dataset jobs only have type `A` or `B`.

I want to add a column `switch` which is set to 1 if, in the current row  the `job_type` column is `A`, and the preceding column is `B`. Otherwise, the value is 0. So the value will be set to zero if the current row is job_type `B` or the current row is job_type `A` and the preceding row is also job_type `A`

The final df would look like this:

```
user_df = read.table(text = "person_id job_number job_type start_date end_date switch
                      1 1 B 2012-11-01 2014-01-01 0
                      1 2 A 2016-02-01 2016-10-01 1
                      1 3 A 2016-12-01 2020-01-01 0
                      1 4 B 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 0
                      2 1 A 2011-03-01 2012-08-01 1
                      2 2 B 2013-01-01 2020-01-01 0
                      2 3 A 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 1
                      2 4 B 2021-01-01 2021-01-17 0
                      3 1 A 2005-03-01 2011-03-01 1
                      3 2 B 2012-01-01 2014-01-01 0", header = T)
```

I know the solution is going to involve `lag` in the `dplyr` library, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible hack would be to treat `job_type == "A"` as a numeric value and then apply the `diff` function to measure change.

`tidyverse` version:

```r
library(dplyr)
user_df %>%
  group_by(person_id) %>%
  mutate(switch = c(0, diff(job_type == "A")),
         switch = ifelse(switch == 1, 1, 0))
```

`data.table` version:

```r
library(data.table)
user_dt = data.table(user_df)
user_dt[, switch := c(0, diff(job_type == "A")), by = .(person_id)][
        , switch := ifelse(switch == 1, 1, 0)]
user_dt

    person_id job_number job_type start_date   end_date switch
 1:         1          1        B 2012-11-01 2014-01-01      0
 2:         1          2        A 2016-02-01 2016-10-01      1
 3:         1          3        A 2016-12-01 2020-01-01      0
 4:         1          4        B 2020-01-01 2021-01-01      0
 5:         2          1        A 2011-03-01 2012-08-01      0
 6:         2          2        B 2013-01-01 2020-01-01      0
 7:         2          3        A 2020-01-01 2021-01-01      1
 8:         2          4        B 2021-01-01 2021-01-17      0
 9:         3          1        A 2005-03-01 2011-03-01      0
10:         3          2        B 2012-01-01 2014-01-01      0
```

Both versions could obviously be executed in a single step, but I thought the idea was clearer this way.

Comment: Actually very clever. Not a hack at all!